# How to maintain daily SNAPSHOT build using TeamCity in C# projects

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, teamcity, nexus, snapshot

I am taking over a project which consists of around 15 projects, whose continuous integration practice was done (the practice was ceased and I need to re-start it in a new environment) by Maven + Nexus OSS + TeamCity and are developed using C#.

What I got, except for those C# solutions themselves, is a `POM` for each of these project, and another parent `POM` (which doesn't contain any code) which every other project has parent of. These development `POM`s only have inter-dependency on SNAPSHOT versions hence the build order is crucial. But these `POM`s that I have do not need any VS plugin, which means (I guess) the compile procedure is not done by `Maven` but by `TeamCity` (VS runner). The `Maven` scripts I have are probably only in charge of e.g., downloading dependencies, validating and installing/deploying/releasing. Unfortunately I can't find any `TeamCity` configurations so I have no clue how this was done before.

EDIT:

I'll try to put some `POM` and script file that I have and see if someone can see some clue on the build procedure.

The files I got from `SVN` are mainly in three kinds categories:

1) The C# source code and project/solution files. Each solution has a 'Dependency' folder which contains all the dependencies, both on other projects on third-party dlls, so that this solution can be built in VS by the developer right after he checkout this solution.

2) The (development) `POM`s.

Firstly I have the POM of the parent project. This project doesn't contain any code but only the `POM` and some scripts (other projects have similar files too). The `POM` looks like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>configuration</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Configuration</name>
... 
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Whether to purge only snapshot artifacts. -->
                            <snapshotsOnly>true</snapshotsOnly>
                            <actTransitively>false</actTransitively>
                            <reResolve>false</reResolve>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${dependencies.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <markersDirectory>${dependencies.markers.directory}</markersDirectory>
                            <useBaseVersion>true</useBaseVersion>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                            <useSubDirectoryPerArtifact>true</useSubDirectoryPerArtifact>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <stripClassifier>true</stripClassifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly-single-zip</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>${assembly.file}</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <attach>false</attach>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-file-snapshot</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${deploy.file}</file>
                            <repositoryId>${nexus.repository.id}</repositoryId>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <url>${nexus.repository.url}</url>
                            <pomFile>${nexus.deploy.pom}</pomFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>clean</preparationGoals>
                    <tagBase>${release.tagBase}</tagBase>       
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>                       
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
...
```

Here we see that the plugins used in the build are `dependency` (to download dependencies), 'assembly' (to package), `deploy` (to deploy files to `Nexus`) and `release`--frankly I can't figure out how it is used. The scripts that I have (I'll describe later) don't use it explicitly and it doesn't seem to be executed in other standard build phases.

And in each of the solution the `POM` has parent of the `configuration`. And they look like this:

`ProjA`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
    <artifactId>configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjA</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ProjA</name>
...     
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

In `ProjB` which depends on `ProjA`, the `POM` is like this:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
    <artifactId>configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjB</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ProjB</name>
...     
<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjA</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

3) Then some .bat scripts as well as deploy.pom and release.pom. 
The `deploy pom` and `release pom` just simply replace the version numbers and declare the dependencies:

deploy.pom for `ProjA`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MY.GROUP</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjA</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
 ..<dependencies>...</dependencies>
```

By `deploy` I assume it means the the deployment of SNAPSHOT version as the version number indicates.

And the `release.pom` are basically the same but change the version to release version (in `ProjA` it is 1.1.1).

In each solution I also have some scripts which I believe are called by `TeamCity`. a) a file called `download.bat`, which basically calls `mvn -U clean` and then `mvn -U validate`. And b) a file called `upload.bat` which basically calls `mvn prepare-package` and then `mvn verify`. In both scripts we pass some mvn options like `-DDeployPomFile， -DNexusUrl, -DRepositoryId`. From the parent `POM` we can see some plugins are executed in those scripts too. And I guess the `download.bat` is called before `TC` is executing the VS build and `upload.bat` is called after the build (assume the target of the build is to publish the latest version).

Above is all I got. I suspect I still miss some `TeamCity` configuration because they are not stored in the `SVN`. But anyway, can somebody help figure out how to manage the daily build? Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually in Maven with Java, you build your projects through the parent pom, and a daily build could be achieved using Jenkins or any other build server. Without a more detailed description of what your compile/build process is, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @JFMeier I understand what you mean. Like I mentioned I don't see any Maven plugin in charge of comping/building and that's why I suspect this procedure is done by `TeamCity` not `Maven` (I suspect in `TeamCity` the build was configured to run some .bat maven script to prepare the dependencies, then run VS runner to build the solution/solutions, and then call another maven script to package/deploy/release). Anyway, I'll try to put more `POM` configuration in the original post and hopefully somebody with similar experience can point me out what might be the procedure.